# How can I get my Canon MF641Cw laser printer to print under the Jammin Jelly release?

Tags: printing

The printer worked fine until I upgraded from Focal Fossa to Jammin Jelly on the same Dell Optiplex 7010 64 bit computer.  I have an HP laptop running the latest version of Linux Mint and the printer works fine there.

Comment: when you switch the printer on and then go to Printers, are you able to add it and then does that selection work?

Comment: I removed all printers listed in settings, and cycled power on the Canon MF641Cw color laser printer.  Then I implemented 'Add Printers' and got three unique responses: Canon_M..ess_Pawp (Model Canon MP64...nprint v5.3.4), CUPS-BRF-Printer (Model Generic Text-Only Printer), and, MP640 (Model MP-640 ser...v5.3.4, driverless).  I have attempted to print using all of the three with no success.